# Google App Script Trigger fails to execute with 100% error rate. Script works fine when manually triggered on editor

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have 2 triggers, onEdit and on Form submit. The 2 triggers seems to be working fine until it just stopped working (fail to execute). I did not touch the script or the trigger settings. However, when i manually run the script on the editor, everything was working fine. The only problem now is that the triggers is always failing (100% error rate).

I have tried deleting the trigger and implementing it again but it does not resolve the problem. The trigger still continue to fail.

Comment: There has been a major Google Apps Script issue this morning.  Might be related:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326802543